ffmpeg - filter complex with split source and multiple overlays: Can my code be simplified?
I've created a complex split filter that splits a single 1372 x 1372 input source into multiple uniquely shaped and cropped slices (s1, s2, etc), and overlays them on a padded background plate into a single output. It also applies a 20fps target framerate on the last overlay step.
It works exactly how I want, but I'm wondering if this code is inefficient or redundant in any way:
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]split=5[s1][s2][s3][s4][s5];
[s1]scale=377:377,crop=360:360:2:2,pad=1920:1080:1560:720[bg];
[s2]crop=1372:1068:0:0[s2];[bg][s2]overlay=0:0[bg];
[s3]crop=460:308:0:1064[s3];[bg][s3]overlay=1372:0[bg];
[s4]crop=460:308:456:1064[s4];[bg][s4]overlay=1372:308[bg];
[s5]crop=460:308:912:1064[s5];[bg][s5]overlay=1372:616,fps=20" output.mp4

Is there a more elegant way to achieve the same result?
